# Returning value from a different row in a CASE

Tags: mysql

I don't know if it is possible, but I thought I could ask

I have a table with families and subfamilies (family_table):

```
family_id  family_name     parent_id
1          Family 1        null
2          Family 2        null
3          Subfamily 1.1   1   
4          Subfamily 1.2   1
5          Family 3        null
6          Subfamily 2.1   2
```

Then I have a complicated SELECT that returns some family_id, like 2, 4.

Then I would need to return the following information:

```
principal_id  family_name     subfamily_id   subfamily_name
2             Family 2        null           null
1             Family 1        4              Subfamily 1.2
```

**EDIT: I wouldn't mind changing how the results are shown or changing something else as long as it is clear enough.**

Here it's what I've done so far:

```
SELECT
    CASE
WHEN ft.parent_id IS NULL THEN
    ft.family_id
ELSE
    ft.parent_id
END AS principal_id, 
/*I was thinking something like this, but I don't know how to select another row value here, or if there would be another way
CASE
WHEN ft.parent_id IS NULL THEN
    ft.family_name
ELSE
    *Family name from the parent*
END AS family_name*/
FROM
    family_table ft
LEFT JOIN family_table ft2 ON ft2.parent_id = ft.family_id
WHERE
    ft.family_id IN (2,4/*complicated select*/)
```

**EDIT: THIS ATTEMPT BELOW WOULDN'T WORK, AS IT RETURNS THE RESULTS FROM A SUBFAMILY AS A FAMILY, and it doesn't join the parent ID from the subfamily, which I need.**

Or maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    ft.family_id as principal_id,
    ft.family_name as family_name,
    ft2.family_id as subfamily_id,
    ft2.family_name as subfamily_name
FROM ft.family_table
LEFT JOIN ft2.family_table ON ft2.parent_id = ft.family_id
WHERE
    /*ft.family_id OR ft2.parent_id*/ IN (2,4/*complicated select*/)
```

I don't want to repeat the monstrous select by doing `ft.family_id IN (2,4/*complicated select*/) OR cf2.parent_id IN (2,4/*complicated select*/)`.
I have the feeling that I am over-complicating everything...

---

**HERE IT IS THE FINAL QUERY, TAKING THE ACCEPTED ANSWER INTO ACCOUNT (in case someone was wondering)**

```
SELECT
    COALESCE (ft2.family_id, ft.family_id) AS family_id,
    COALESCE (ft2.family_name, ft.family_name) AS family_name,
    CASE WHEN ft.parent_id IS NOT NULL THEN ft.family_id
    END AS subfamily_id,
    CASE WHEN ft.parent_id IS NOT NULL THEN ft.family_name
    END AS subfamily_name
FROM family_table ft
JOIN (/* complicated select */) AS t ON t.family_id IN (ft.family_id, ft.parent_id)
LEFT JOIN family_table ft2 ON ft2.family_id = ft.parent_id
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue with the last attempt using a self join? That's exactly what I would use.

Comment: Then join to the complicated select, and use simple `COPLICATED_SELECT_COLUMN IN(parent_id,family_id)`

Comment: @Shadow, the problem is ft.family_id OR cf2.parent_id IN (2,4/*complicated select*/) doesn't work, and I do not want to repeat the select inside the IN, because it is extremely long and it takes ages.

Comment: @sagi, could you develop that idea a little more? I don't think I understand what you mean

Comment: @Ika Look at my answer.

Comment: I do not think that you need to repeat the complex subquery twice, the criteria on the parent_id is not required. As a result of the join you cannot have any parent_id value that do not satisfy the criteria set for the family_id.

Comment: @Shadow But then how do I join the parent_id to the subfamily_id in order to have both family and subfamily names and ids?

Comment: The join stays the same. You just do not need the extra bit in the where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try joining to the "complicated select" instead of using `IN()` , something like this:

```
SELECT
.....
FROM
    family_table ft
LEFT JOIN family_table ft2 ON ft2.parent_id = ft.family_id
JOIN ( /* complicated select here */ ) t
 ON(t.ID_OR_WHATEVER IN(ft.family_id,cf2.parent_id))
```

This will have the same effect.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Neither this or my second proposal would work, as it returns these fields with info from the subfamily... 

 ft.family_id as principal_id,
 ft.family_name as family_name,